# Exception while running a TestNG test

Tags: java, intellij-idea, testng, intellij-14

I cannot seem to run any test at all as I am getting the following exception:

> java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG$DelegatingTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(Lorg/testng/ISuite;Lorg/testng/xml/XmlTest;Ljava/util/Collection;Ljava/util/List;)Lorg/testng/TestRunner;
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunner$ProxyTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner

We use TestNG, and the jar file I have in my dependencies is the following:

testng.6.9.12

Any ideas?

Comment: the issue might be with the testng.jar. try with different version of testng.

Comment: You should open an issue on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues?q=%23%7BUnit%20Testing.%20TestNG%7D%20 but I think IDEA14 is too old and won't support new TestNG versions.

Comment: Strange . A couple of days ago the tests were running fine. If it was a version upgrade of testng.jar, shouldnt it work by doing a clean rebuild?    Our  build system is  gradle and we have multiple projects.

Answer (score 6):

Upgrading to the latest version of IntelliJ 2016.1 fixed the issue.

Comment: I also had to upgrade to IntelliJ 2016 to fix this. I tried IntelliJ 14 and 15 with no luck.

Answer (score 5):

I also had the AbstractMethodError while running a testNG suite. Here was the solution that worked for me:

1. Open the Registry in Intellij

   - (On a Mac)
   - Press: Command Option Shift /
   - Click: Registry...
2. Check the testng_sm_runner box value

Basically, I followed the instructions here:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-143967#comment=27-1089937

Answer (score 0):

You can try by updating the *TestNG* plugin of your IDE. 
There are chances that the *TestNG* version you are using and *TestNG* plugin that is installed in your IDE is not compatible. So after updating, there is a chance that
it will work.